# Jello effect when displaying a filtered digital signal

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, numpy, signal-processing

I wish to display a mesured signal in real time with some basic filtering (band stop, band pass).

- signal is stored in a numpy array ([numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html))
- a matplotlib graph is displaying the numpy array ([matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation))
- for each FuncAnimation frame, some filters are applied on the signal ([scipy.signal.butter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html), [scipy.signal.filtfilt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html))

When I do it this way, I get some kind of jello effet (sorry for bad gif quality)

[image: jello effect]

Even if it's not exactly what's going on, let's pretend I implemented this algorithm in pseudo-code:

```
 signal = np.array(some_data)
 plot = FuncAnimation(init_function, update_function)

 for each frame:
   - shift signal on the left # make space and discard oldest samples
   - add new samples on the right
   - filtered_signal = filter(signal) # using signal.butter and signal.filtfilt
   - update_plot(filtered_signal) # FuncAnimation update function
```

I'm looking for techniques to get rid of this unwanted effect. Any idea?

**EDIT 1**

Without animation, this is what append for 20 consecutive filtered signals.

[image]

- First plot is `signal` (raw signal)
- Second plot contains the 20 last `filtered_signal`
- Third plot contains the 20 last `filtered_signal` shifted for better visualization

**EDIT 2**

- `signal` is a fixed-size buffer containing N=1000 samples
- `filtered_signal` is created from scratch for each frame
- sampling frequency is fs=250Hz
- 2 filters are applied: a 50Hz notch and a [0.5Hz, 120Hz] band pass

**EDIT 3**
Here is a full working example:

- First plot is the raw signal
- Second plot is the filtered signal (band pass [0.5Hz, 120Hz])

Source code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time


N = 1000
fs = 250
last_update = time.time()
sample_id = 0


def all_samples(length=10000):
    # generate a dummy signal
    st = 1.0 / fs
    t = np.arange(length) * st
    sig1 = 1*np.sin(2*np.pi * 2*t) + 2
    sig2 = 0.25*np.sin(2*np.pi * 3*t) + 4
    sig3 = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi * 4*t) + 5
    return sig1 + sig2 + sig3


def band_pass(low_cut, high_cut, order=2):
    # compute butterworth b, a coefficients
    band = np.array([low_cut, high_cut])
    Wn = band / (float(fs/2.0))
    b, a = signal.butter(order, Wn, 'bandpass')
    return b, a


def filter(raw_signal):
    # apply filter 
    b, a = band_pass(0.5, 120)
    return signal.filtfilt(b, a, raw_signal)


def init():
    # init function for FuncAnimation blit=True
    global axe_raw, line_raw
    global axe_filt, line_filt
    line_filt.set_visible(False)
    line_raw.set_visible(False)
    axe_raw.set_xlim(0, 1000)
    axe_raw.set_ylim(5, 15)
    axe_filt.set_xlim(0, 1000)
    axe_filt.set_ylim(-5, 5)
    return line_raw, line_filt,


def update(n):
    global raw_signal, axe_raw, line_raw
    global axe_filt, line_filt
    global last_update, fs, sample_id
    if n == 1:
        line_raw.set_visible(True)
        line_filt.set_visible(True)

    # add new samples
    now = time.time()
    sample_count = int((now - last_update) * fs)
    raw_signal = np.roll(raw_signal, -sample_count)
    raw_signal[-sample_count:] = all_samples[sample_id:sample_id + sample_count]
    last_update = now
    sample_id += sample_count

    # update plot (raw + filtered)
    line_raw.set_ydata(raw_signal)
    line_filt.set_ydata(filter(raw_signal))


    return line_raw, line_filt


all_samples = all_samples()
raw_signal = np.zeros(N)

# matplotlib animation
figure = plt.figure()
axe_raw = figure.add_subplot(211)
axe_filt = figure.add_subplot(212)
line_raw, = axe_raw.plot(raw_signal)
line_filt, = axe_filt.plot(np.zeros(N))
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(figure,
                               update,
                               init_func=init,
                               interval=5,
                               blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The jello effect is the jumping signal? Did you check whether this is due to the fact that you filter parts of your signal several times? Your data is filtered, then you discard parts of it and add unfiltered new signal. Then you filter everything again... Especially in the transit zone of the butterworth filter, this could have an effect.

Comment: Yes, the jumping effect, I don't know how to name it. `signal` always contains raw data. Each time I take this raw data, apply 2 filters (well, 4 since `filtfilt` apply a linear filter twice, once forward and once backwards) and then, display this freshly created numpy array. I will still make sure `id` function returns differents values.

Comment: it is hard (at least for me) to determine, whether this is a problem of your data processing or of the animation process. If you do not animate, but simply create a few frames as array and compare them, is the jumping present in between them, too? Is the filtering done in a way that ensures that frames following each other match with their data?

Comment: From your previous comment, something is bugging me: `id(signal)` and `id(filtered)` are indeed always different, but `id(signal)` is not always the same, so it may be a problem in my code. I may be a good clue and I will investigate further.

Comment: I take it that you're not displaying every single data point. In that case you're running up against Nyquist sampling limitations - the data contains frequencies higher than what can be displayed, and aliasing is causing the signal to jump around. You need to apply a filter to remove the high frequencies before display.

Comment: I display every single data points I have at a given time. I use a fixed size buffer that I called `signal`, containing N=1000 samples. The sampling rate is fs=250Hz. Each time a new sample is pushed in `signal`, older samples are shifted on the left (oldest samples are discarded) and the new sample is inserted on the right. I apply 2 filters at the moment: a 50Hz notch and a [0.5Hz,120Hz] band pass. What should I do ?

Comment: I feel like this would be much easier to diagnose with a MWE and some test data.

Comment: Done. It may not be the most relevant test data, but it clearly shows the effect.

Comment: You may pass 1000 samples into the display function, but that doesn't mean it's generating 1000 points on the graph. If the display function does sampling of the input, you need to ensure those samples meet Nyquist limits.

Comment: @MarkRansom In the source code example I provided, `signal.filtfilt(b, a, raw_signal)` generates an array of 1000 values from 1000 input samples. How do I ensure input samples meet Nyquist limits?

Comment: Just apply another low pass filter, experiment with the cutoff until the jumpiness goes away.

Comment: I experimented with some low pass filters, even with very low cutoff, and I still get a jumpy filtered signal. Maybe butterworth filters are not meant to be used for real time displaying ?